# Pattern to last digits for powers of primes

Tags: combinatorics

All the powers of five end in a five, and all the powers of two are even. Show that for some integer $n$, if you take the first $n$ powers of a prime other than two or five, one must have "$01$" as the last two digits.

I have no idea where to start here, I tried finding the powers of some primes to try and find a pattern and I found
If the prime ends in 1, it is every time. (1, 1, 1, 1 ...)
If it ends in 3, it's every 4th time. (3, 9, 7, 1, ....)
If it ends in 7, it's every 4th time. (7, 9, 3, 1, ....)
If it ends in 9, it's every 2nd time. (9, 1, 9, 1, ....)

But I have no idea how to show that every prime can be raised to a power that results in the last two digits ending in "$01$"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A prime $p\neq 2,5$ can be viewed as living in the finite group
$$
\left(\Bbb Z/100\Bbb Z\right)^\times = \{x\in\Bbb Z/100\Bbb Z\mid\textrm{ there exists }y\in\Bbb Z/100\Bbb Z\textrm{ such that }xy\equiv 1\pmod{100}\},
$$
since invertible elements modulo $m$ are precisely those $n$ satisfying $\gcd(n,m) = 1$. Now $n\in\Bbb Z$ ends in $01$ if and only if $n\equiv 1\pmod{100}$ . By [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) we have $p^{\phi(100)}\equiv 1\pmod{100}$, so $p$ raised to the $\phi(100)$th power will have last two digits $01$ (here $\phi(n)$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)).

Comment: In symbols, *there exists* is denoted by $\exists$. *There exists only one* is denoted by $\exists!$. *There does not exist* is denoted by $\neg\exists$ or more commonly, $\nexists$. And, *there exists infinitely many* is denoted by $\exists^\infty$.